# Reduce spacing between title, author and date in knitR document and shift title further up the page

Tags: r-markdown

The following is the default way to create a title in R markdown.

```
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "19/02/2020"
output: pdf_document
```

The problem is that the 3 lines (title, author, date) occupy too much space. I would like to know a way to reduce the font size of all 3 lines, reduce the margin between the lines, and shift the lines a bit higher up the page. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59843585/reduce-title-margins-when-creating-pdf-from-rmarkdown-using-knitr

title: \vspace{-1.5cm} test 

This reduced the space between the top of the page and the title for me.